# Overflowing content outside parent div in ie6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

The following code:

```
<div style="width: 50px; border: 1px solid green;">
    <div style="position: absolute;">
        whatever text you want
    </div>
</div>
```

Renders like this:

[image: Modern browsers]

in any modern browser(ie7+, chrome, firefox), and like this:

[image: IE6]

in IE6.

What i would like is for it to render in IE6 just like it renders in the others browsers.
Any ideas ?

Comment: IE6 = less than 2% market share and falling. Do you *really* need to support it?

Comment: I do unfortunately when the paying customer asks for it.

Comment: @Spudley: When the client is monitoring your progress at work on IE6, or your're building a site for the government, it's in your interest to support IE6. When it's your personal blog or your Dog's home page, it's probably not important.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using `position: absolute`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just put the text outside the div?

```
<div style="width: 50px; border: 1px solid green;">
</div>
whatever text you want
```

Or

```
<div style="width: 50px; border: 1px solid green;">
    <div style="position:absolute; width:XXpx">whatever text you want</div>
</div>
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: You missed my point. Imagine i can't change the way the top div in rendered, but i want to insert content inside it that overflows outside of it.

Comment: to update: because that's not what i need. I need content on a child div to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with IE6. (one of many)

This site discusses the problem and how to work around it: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/expandingboxbug.html

Comment: I had already seen that website, but i can't seem to understand how that applies to my example. Sorry to push it, but can you point me to the fixed applied to my example code ?

Comment: Its been a long time since I used IE6, and I don't have it on my PC any more, so I can't give you a tested answer. But my suggestion would be the same as from that page I linked to: Try adding the `word-wrap` property with the value `break-word`.